# How can I connect 2 react projects with one socket server? And let them communicate via socket?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

I want two separate react projects to communicate with each other through below provided code-base.
So if I tap on counter1 on project-1, counter1 of project-2 gets updates automatically without refreshing the page.

```
parentDirectory:
    project-1:
        ReactProject1
    project-2:
        ReactProject2
    socketServer
        index.js (Socket.io)
```

- 

Index.js:

```
import { Server } from "socket.io";

const io = new Server(3001, {
    cors: {
        origin: '*',
    }
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.emit('welcome', 'connection established');
    socket.on('msg', (data) => {
        let dataArr = data.split("--")
        console.log(dataArr[0], dataArr[1])
        socket.emit('update1', data);
        socket.emit('update2', data);
    })
})
```

---

App.js: (Project1)

```
import './App.css';

import React from 'react'
import CounterButton from './components/counter-button';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io("http://localhost:3001")

function App() {
  let [counter1, setCounter1] = React.useState(0);
  let [counter2, setCounter2] = React.useState(0);
  let [counter3, setCounter3] = React.useState(0);
  // let [socketio, setSocket] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('connect', () => {
      socket.on('update1', (data) => {
        let dataArr = data.split('--')
        console.log("Im here", data)
        let index = dataArr[0] - 0;
        let value = dataArr[1] - 0;
        if (index == 0) {
          setCounter1(value)
        }
        else if (index == 1) {
          setCounter2(value)
        }
        else if (index == 2) {
          setCounter3(value)
        }
      })
    })
  }, []);





  const messageServer = (index, newValue) => {
    socket.emit('msg', "" + index + "--" + newValue);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className='button-row' style={{ "display": "flex", "flexDirection": "row", "gap": "20px" }}>
        <CounterButton buttonName={1}
          value={counter1}
          onClick={() => { messageServer(0, counter1 + 1) }}
        />
        <CounterButton buttonName={2}
          value={counter2}
          onClick={() => { messageServer(1, counter2 + 1) }}
        />
        <CounterButton buttonName={3}
          value={counter3}
          onClick={() => { messageServer(2, counter3 + 1) }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

---

App.js (Project 2):

Same as App.js in project1, just React.useEffect has 'update2' in socket listener.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('connect', () => {
      socket.on('update2', (data) => {
        let dataArr = data.split('--')
        console.log("Im here", data)
        let index = dataArr[0] - 0;
        let value = dataArr[1] - 0;
        if (index == 0) {
          setCounter1(value)
        }
        else if (index == 1) {
          setCounter2(value)
        }
        else if (index == 2) {
          setCounter3(value)
        }
      })
    })
  }, []);
```